# fullscreeen button behaves differently in Chrome and FireFox/IE

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen, autodesk-forge

From this website, https://derivatives.autodesk.io/

when you view a 3D model using Forge Viewer, when user clicks "fullscreen" button, the icon is displayed incorrectly in Chrome(user should be able to see "exit fullscreen" button instead of "fullscreen" button if it's already in "fullscreen")
in Firefox or IE, it behaves correctly. Is this a Forge Viewer bug in Chrome? Any fix?

Comment: What happens for you on other sites using the viewer, like http://a360.autodesk.com? I experience everywhere the same behaviour on both Mac and Windows, in all browsers, including the https://derivatives.autodesk.io/ sample: in fullscreen mode an extra toolbar appears saying "Press esc to exit full screen", and the full screen button icon on the main toolbar changes to the exit full screen icon, but the tooltip still says "Full screen"

Comment: yes, label is always incorrect no matter where from a360.autodesk.com, but at least the icon is correct. And from https://derivatives.autodesk.io/, Firefox/IE behaves correctly, Chrome does not. There might be some toggle setting is not handled correctly in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be a combination of the sample using viewer3D.js (so that I could debug into the code) instead of viewer3D.min.js and maybe the [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) network providing wrong resources in cases of certain locations. I'm saying the latter, because when I'm checking the sample from Chrome in the UK network then it works fine, when I log into our company [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) (which is based in another country) then the problem occurs. I'll update the code and will get it pushed to [derivatives.autodesk.io](http://derivatives.autodesk.io). Let's hope that will solve it.

PS: today even logged in to our VPN the sample works fine in Chrome (maybe our VPN is going though a different country today?). So it seems a rather inconsistent issue. :-/ Even if I changed now the sample to use viewer3D.min.js I could not tell if it made any difference, since now again I cannot reproduce the issue in the sample's current state either.